# how to map the "=>" rails operator as shortcut in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

In insert mode I'd like to get this working, so I can use the shortcut in a rails file.

```
imap <C-,> =>
```

Thanks for advise!

Comment: It seems that Vim doesn't support it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659487/vim-gvim-key-mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to create a 2-keys shortcut for a 2-keys + modifier sequence?

As @Tassos commented it doesn't seem to be possible but if you REALLY think typing `=>` is too slow you can use the mapleader (see `:help mapleader`) like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let mapleader=","
imap <leader>= =>
```

Comment: For what reason you write here `<leader>=` instead of `,=` and `imap` instead of `inoremap`? I strongly suggest using `inoremap` because it is immune to whatever user placed in vimrc and not using `<leader>` for vimrc mappings because I do not see why I should make my own mappings dependent on variables (plugin mappings are different case).

Comment: @ZyX, I wrote `imap` instead of the preferred `inoremap` because the asker is already using `imap`. I presumed it was a conscious choice. I fundamentally agree with you for `<leader>` but I find it quite useful when some plugins make use of it by default: it make their shortcuts very intuitive. Because they are all assigned to `<leader>something` and I have `set mapleader=","` I don't have to use the awful default `<leader>` or remap their shortcuts and I'm able to quickly use the plugin effectively.

Comment: That is why I said «plugin mappings are different case». (I though prefer to use `,` as a leader only for my mappings and leave plugin mappings as-is or explicitely map to them.)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps an abbreviation would be more useful? For example, you can use this to automatically convert `>` to `=>` in insert mode.

```
iabbr > =>
```

There are certain rules for when an abbreviation will be expanded, so this will not change every `>` to `=>`, which you probably don't want anyway. See [abbreviations](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#Abbreviations) for more details about this.

Comment: `inorebbrev`. It is more deterministic.